# Bing Maps in Windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, bing-maps

My question is similar to this one "[https://bitly.com/UaQOC4](https://bitly.com/UaQOC4+)", but that question is somewhat misleading.

In my Windows 8 Store app, I have a Bing map reference to a particular location somewhere in South Africa. The referenced location will have multiple pins to denote key areas of interest to users of the application, with an info window for each of the pins.

When a user clicks on a pin, the info window will give them more information, like statistics around the location and a link to a page within the application, for example: /pages/nests/crowsnest.html.

What I need is to be able to push the user, when clicked on the location in the info window, to this page, however, this does not seem to be allowed.

From my understanding, we're trying to force a page load from within the current domain space (our application) from outside of the application scope (info window == iframe) as this is not a web page, this seems to be disallowed.

Is my assumption correct in that we're trying to break the domain policy here? I don't see how we can, as we're just redirecting users to a page.

I have tried the WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/nests/crowsnets.html") and event a normal -tag but neither of these approaches allowed me any success.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what are you trying to achieve. You can use Bing Maps control in your Windows 8 app and you can pin any Pushpins in there, You can also handle the behavior when user taps any pin and show more detailed info on the map.
[Bing Maps SDK for Windows Store apps](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca)